# how can I plot loss-step relationship of DNNregressor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm evaluation DNNregressor in tensorflow. I want to find a best training step by plotting loss-step relationship. Is there a function or api that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but for anyone who comes later, those snippets are what I have used to evaluate loss-step relationship. I hope someone will find it useful.

```
# Collect errors to evaluate performance.
errorlist = [];

# Fit model by passing multiple times.
numberOfIterations = 5;
for i in range(numberOfIterations):

    # Fit the model
    regressor.fit(x=X,y=Y,steps=5000)

    # Get the error
    y = list(regressor.predict(X, as_iterable=True))
    error = mean_squared_error(Y,y)
    errorlist = np.append(errorlist,error)

    # Inform the user about remaining iterations
    print("Remaining:",numberOfIterations-i)
```

And to plot the errors that you collected up to here you can easily do so by matplotlib.

```
# Plot errors
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(errorlist,'g');
plt.title("Mean Squarred Error")
plt.xlabel("Batch Iteration Number (x5000)")
plt.ylabel("Error")
```